# Dot above capital letter not centred

Tags: fonts, xetex

When I write the following lines, the dots above the capital letters are all shifted to the left (see picture). Anyone know how to fix this so that the dots are more centred above the capitals? Thanks!

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{align*}
    \dot{S} &= \mu N - \beta_W WS - \beta_I SI - \mu S \\
    \dot{I} &= \beta_W WS + \beta_I SI - \gamma I - \mu I \\
    \dot{W} &= \alpha I - \xi W \\
    \dot{R} &= \gamma I - \mu R
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Update: The error only occurs when compiling with **XeLaTeX** and not pdfLaTeX, but the template requires XeLaTeX for proper fonts.

Comment: I can confirm your problem when compiling with xelatex.

Answer (score 10):

We need `XeLaTeX` and `fontspec` package to use system fonts.

In general, using a system font will load a bitmap font by default. To fix this, you should load a vector font. This can be achieved by loading the package `lmodern`.

Add package `lmodern` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{align*}
    \dot{S} &= \mu N - \beta_W WS - \beta_I SI - \mu S \\
    \dot{I} &= \beta_W WS + \beta_I SI - \gamma I - \mu I \\
    \dot{W} &= \alpha I - \xi W \\
    \dot{R} &= \gamma I - \mu R
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, what's the reason?

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah - I have updated the answer